# Error "Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting the error on the title when trying to execute the t-sql stored procedure

```
EXEC Add500ToChecking 18568
```

I tried deleting the return and the go statements but it didn't work

```
USE [JProCo]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[Add500ToChecking] @CustID INT AS

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE SavAccount SET Balance = Balance - 500
WHERE CustomerID = @CustID
IF ( (SELECT Balance FROM SavAccount WHERE CustomerID = @CustID) < 0)
ROLLBACK TRAN
RETURN

UPDATE CkAccount SET Balance = Balance + 500
WHERE CustomerID = @CustID

COMMIT TRAN
RETURN
GO
```

Any idea of what's going on with my code? This is for a class project

Comment: Make a habit of surrounding the conditional block with BEGIN and END.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will. That code is verbatim from the class test book (joes2pros), so it took me some time to ask for help here :)

Comment: Not the first time I've seen code bugs slip through tech edits. In addition to BEGIN/END, I suggest following an indention style and using semi-colon statement terminators, That makes intent clearer and code easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a pair of `BEGIN` and `END` for your `IF` statement:

```
UPDATE SavAccount SET Balance = Balance - 500
WHERE CustomerID = @CustID
IF ( (SELECT Balance FROM SavAccount WHERE CustomerID = @CustID) < 0)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN
END
```

As written, only the `ROLLBACK TRAN` is part of the `IF` statement, so if it fails the `IF` check, it doesn't rollback the transaction, but immediately executes `RETURN`.

Comment: Probably should re-word "so if it fails the if check" to "so if it does not meet the if condition". In this example, the condition is looking for a failure so that it can do something, so it's slightly ambiguous what was meant.